# Is there any way I can mirror the display from a Windows Phone 8 device for a presentation?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way I can mirror the display from a Windows Phone 8 device for a presentation?

Either with a VGA adapter cable, or using software running on a laptop connected to the device via USB (similar software exists for BlackBerry and Android).

We can't use the emulator because our software uses audio codecs that aren't supported on it.

Comment: Might get better answer on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would entirely be dependent on the device itself.

Comment: We have several models: Nokia Lumia 920 and 620, HTC 8S and 8X

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2010/106

Comment: Or, for 8.1: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3540/106